# Apply a user defined function to all combinations of rows from two 3D torch tensors without using for loop

Tags: pytorch, parallel-processing

***What I have:***
I have two torch tensors `T1` of dimension `mxdxN` and `T2` of dimension `nxdxN`, I have a function `foo` which takes two torch tensors of dimensions `dxN` and returns a scalar.

***Output I want:***
I want to apply the function `foo` to all combinations of rows from `T1` and `T2`, and save the outputs to another 2D torch tensor, say `O` of dimension `mxn`. So `O[i,j]=foo(T1[i], T2[j])`.

***Naive solution, I am using now:***
Use two for loop over rows from `T1` and `T2` and apply `foo` and save the output.

***Improved solution, I am looking for:***
How can I implement `foo` to `T1` and `T2` (or some views of them), and get the output `O` directly?

I am currently using the time-consuming naive solution mentioned above.